# Delete network file without warning in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, finder

When I press Command-Delete to delete a file on a network file system in macOS Big Sur, I get a warning that says:

> "Are you sure you want to delete '...'"?
>
> This item will be deleted immediately. You can't undo this action

This warning does not occur when deleting a file from a local drive.

Is there a way to suppress this warning when deleting a file on a network file system?